# Strange results/errors when using phonegap 3.1 for local build for android

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I'm using phonegap 3 to create apps on my local pc.

I can create the app ok using

phonegap create "appname"

I can set the directory without issue

cd appname

When I come to build it for android I get this message

**[error] The command 'android' failed. Make sure you have the latest Android SDK installed, and the 'android' command added to your path. Output:**

However, just once I was able to create an app with success. I copied the output folders in windows explorer and changed its name. I was then able to go back to the command line and goto the copied apps directory and build it without issue.

Very strange as this would indicate that the android build works correctly.

Anyone else faced this issue or know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your command prompt enter "android" and see if it works. You should be able to see the android sdk manager window.

If not, you should download and add the android tools folder in your system PATH system variable.

Once done, try again the above and now it should work.

I guess before it worked for you because Eclipse is configured to the path of Android SDK.